# Collapse not working in Angular navbar for mobile

Tags: html, angular, mdbootstrap

I have an Angular project without Jquery.
I want to have a navbar with mdbootstrap, But when I write mdbootstrap code in my html, collapse does not work.
Here is my html content.

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark primary-color">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: You need to give us more informations Did you install it correct ? Here is step by step how to install this lib in angular project as no Pro member: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/quick-start/

Comment: yes I install everything correctly. but because I don't use jquery, not work

Comment: So if you want to make it work, you need to install jquery. If you dont want to try to use `Angular Material` library.

Comment: I'll answer the question on how to make really good navbar using only Angular material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/navigation/compositions/) is not very user-friendly, but still goes over the basic navbar... the classes use tell it when to move from hanburger menu to expanded form (`navbar-expand-lg` in our case); the rest is just dummy text in the example below.

relevant **HTML**:

```
<mdb-navbar SideClass="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark pink ie-nav" [containerInside]="false">
    <mdb-navbar-brand>
        <a class="logo navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>Navbar</strong></a>
    </mdb-navbar-brand>
    <links>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>
                <a class="nav-link">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>
                <a class="nav-link">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>
                <a class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>
                <a class="nav-link">Opinions</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-flex-icons">
            <li class="nav-item waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>
                <a class="nav-link"><mdb-icon fab icon="facebook-f"></mdb-icon></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>
                <a class="nav-link"><mdb-icon fab icon="twitter"></mdb-icon></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>
                <a class="nav-link"><mdb-icon fab icon="instagram"></mdb-icon></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </links>
</mdb-navbar>
```

relevant **CSS**:

```
.navbar-toggler-icon{ border:2px solid red;}
.navbar-brand, .nav-link{color:red !important;}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqqkd4)

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting the best way using `Angular Material` library to make sidenav as main nav of your application. You no need to install any other librarys then `Angular Material`

`npm i --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations`

`ng add @angular/material`

Here is a code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c8gpuh

Here is an video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6qhzG7mObU

And in your app.component.html:

```
<sidenav-autosize-example>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</sidenav-autosize-example>
```

And remember to import nessesery modules to your project:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { MatSidenavModule, MatToolbarModule, MatButtonModule, MatIconModule, MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        MatSidenavModule,
        // MatToolbarModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatIconModule,
        // MatProgressBarModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        MatSidenavModule,
        // MatToolbarModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatIconModule,
        // MatProgressBarModule,
    ],
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```